# How to throw a compile error if the include paths for a library were set up not as intended

Tags: c++

Our C++ library contains a file with a namethat is (considered) equal to one of the standard libraries' headers. In our case this is "String.h", which Windows considers to be the same as "string.h", but for the sake of this question it could be any other ile name used in the standard library.

Normally, this file name ambiguity is not a problem since a user is supposed to set up the include paths to only include the parent of the library folder (therefore requiring to include "LibraryFolder/String.h") and not the folder containing the header.

However, sometimes users get this wrong and directly set the include path  to the containing folder. This means that "String.h" will be included in place of "string.h" in both the user code and in the standard library headers, resulting in a lot of compile errors that may not be easy to resolve or understand for beginners.

Is it possible, during compile-time, to detect such wrongly set up include paths in our libraries' header and throw a compile #warning or #error right away via directive, based on some sort of check on how the inclusion path was?

Comment: Maybe now is the time to switch to `std::string` or at least rename the header.

Comment: Good question, but IMO this is an IDE problem. The "Add an Include Directory" task is _far_ too hard. Here's a hint to IDE writers: There should be a right-click option on `#include "Foo/Bar.h"` to localize `Bar.h` in the file system, and then set up the include path such that `Foo/Bar.h` works.

Comment: @nwp this is a general question so lets please not focus on std:.string, as the exact same would happen if the library had another header that has a filename identical to one of the hundreds of header names of the standard library.

Comment: Well, the solution is also general. Switching to the standard types or renaming the headers should always solve the ambiguity.

Comment: Define your own namespace and prohibit `using namespace xxx` in your files. This way you should never have conflicts and you will get compile error if you include the wrong header.

Comment: @atoMerz that's not correct. Namespace or not, if you include the wrong file then things will break.

Comment: @Ident if you have namespaced your identifiers, then the breakage **will** be compile time, rather than **probably** compile time / link time

Comment: @Ident It'll break. I suggest you read [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace) or any other related resource to get a better understanding of namespaces. Quoting the first sentence from there: `Namespaces provide a method for preventing name conflicts in large `. IMO this is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @atoMerz, Caleth: you seem to not understand. The namespace won't come into effect *at all* if the file using said namespace is never included in the first place because an equally (or consider equally) named file is included instead. This should be evident.

Comment: @Ident I tried to explain how it solves your problem as an answer. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[edit - as per comments]
Header inclusion can be summarized as :

- Parse `#include` line to determine header name to look up
- Depending on `<Foo.h>` or `"Foo.h"` form, determine set of locations (usually directories) to search
- Interpret the header name, in an implementation-dependent way. (usually as a relative path). Note that this is not necessarily as a string, e.g. MSVC doesn't treat `\` as a string escape character.
- If the header is found (usually, if a file is found), replace the `#include`  line with the content of that file. If not, fail the compilation.

(The parenthesized "usually" apply to MSVC, GCC, clang, etc but theoretically a compiler could compile directly from a git repository instead of disk files)

The problem here is that the test imagined (spelling of header name) must be located in the included header file. This test would necessarily be part of the replaced `#include` line, which *therefore* no longer exists and cannot be tested.

C++17 introduces `__has_include` but this does not affect the analysis: It would still have to occur in the included header file, and would not have the character sequence from the `#include "Foo.h"` available.

[old]
Probably the easiest way, especially for beginners is to have a `LibraryName/LibraryName.h`. Hopefully that name is unique.

The benefit is that once that works, users can replace `#include "LibraryName.h"` with just `#include "String.h"` as you know the path is right.

That said, `"String.h"` is asking for problems. Windows isn't case sensitive.

Comment: I do not quite understand how your suggestion relates to the problem at all. Besides, imo the user should never have to include "String.h" directly, it should always be in the subfolder of a library to prevent collisions with internal or external headers.

Comment: @Ident: I am obviously misunderstanding your question then. Are you somehow asking whether you can check the token sequence in `#include " ... "` ? Because you can't from your header. That preprocessor directive is _replaced_ with the content of your header. Hence, anything in your header cannot even see that line anymore.

Comment: My question is if there is any way to check if the level of hierarchy via which the file is included (i.e. "header.h" vs "someFolder/header.h" vs "someFolder/someOtherFolder/header.h") is possible to be checked somehow. If it i is as you say, i.e. it is replaced, then the answer to my question would probably just be "no" and that would be already as helpful as an answer then can be ;)

Comment: Reading your answer again, I think you understood the problem perfectly. The first part of your edited answer is very helpful and seems to confirm it is not possible to check the inclusion path.

Answer (score 4):

There's no failsafe way. If the compiler finds another file, it won't complain.

However, you could make it so you can detect it. In your own `LibraryName/string.h`, you could define a unique symbol, like

```
#define MY_STRING_H412a55af_7643_4bd6_be5c_4315d3a1e6b7
```

Then later in dependent code you could check

```
#ifndef MY_STRING_H412a55af_7643_4bd6_be5c_4315d3a1e6b7
     #error "Custom standard library path not configured correctly"
#endif
```

Likewise you could use this to detect when the wrong version of the library was included.

Comment: I would suggest to add the #ifndef .. #endif clause right after the inclusion in every file, this way an automatic script can verify that all string inclusions are correct

Comment: @DanielTrugman that might make sense. However, in a setting where the `string.h` is included indirectly (e.g. a precompiled header) there might not be more than 1 location

Comment: you are right. An additional whitelist will solve that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `namespace`s. In your case this would translate into something like this:

```
MyString/String.h
namespace my_namespace {
  class string {
    ...
  }
}
```

Now to make sure your `std::string` or any other class named `string` is not *accidentally* used instead of `my_namespace::string` (by any means, including but not limited to setting up your include paths incorrectly) you need to refer to your type using its fully qualified name, namely `my_namespace::string`. By doing this you avoid any naming clashes and are guaranteed to get a compile error if you don't include the correct header file (unless there's actually exists another class called `my_namespace::string` that is not yours). There are other ways to avoid these clashes (such as `using my_namespace::string`) but I'd rather be explicit about the types I'm using. This solution is costly however because it probably needs change all over your code base (changing all `strings` to `my_namespace::string`).

A somewhat less cumbersome alternative would be to change the name of the header `String.h` to something like `MyString.h`. This would quickly introduce compile errors but requires changing all your includes from `#include "String.h" into`#include "MyString.h"` (Should be much less effort compared to the first option).

I cannot think of any other way that requires less effort as of now. Since you were looking for a solution that would work in all similar scenarios I'd go with the `namespace`s if I were you and solve the problem once and for all. This would prevent any other existing/future naming clashes that may be in you code.

Comment: That does solves nameclash problems but any functions defined in the X.h ,that is intended to be included, that are not present in the erroneously included X.h (from another library) will simply not be there and lead to compile errors such as undefined symbols etc.

Comment: @Ident Indeed you will get compile error for anything (be it a type, function, enum, etc...). Isn't that what you have asked for in the question? `How to detect such wrong set up paths and throw a compile warning or error right away`.

Comment: By now it has become pretty clear to me that I did not pose my question well enough. I would have liked to produce a an error message on compile, yes, but a more comprehensive one than whatever the first of many issues is that comes up if you miss an include. Something more along the lines of an targeted #error directive like "You included this wrong, do this to fix it" but I am afraid this is actually not supported as it seems. I will adjust my question to make it more clear what I meant.

Comment: There would be no easy way to do what you're asking for. I cannot think of anything better than sehe's answer ATM and that would require you to check the existence of the macro pretty much all over your code. However, IMHO, my proposed solution comes pretty close to what your asking for. That is, you will get an error which would look something like `Identifier 'my_namespace::xxx' is undefined`. This points out to a header file inclusion problem, although it doesn't exactly say that.